# Hibernate criteria result Mapping to Class/Bean

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to find third highest salary

Result should be: "Mark", "Hastings", Gender.male, 60000,"USA"

Here is the data

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee("Mark", "Hastings", Gender.male, 60000,"USA");
Employee employee2 = new Employee("Steve", "Pound", Gender.male, 45000, "USA");
Employee employee3 = new Employee("Ben", "Hoskins", Gender.male, 70000, "USA");
Employee employee4 = new Employee("Philip", "Hastings",Gender.male, 45000, "USA");
Employee employee5 = new Employee("Mary", "Lambeth",Gender.female, 30000, "UK");
Employee employee6 = new Employee("Valarie", "Vikings",Gender.female, 35000,"UK");
Employee employee7 = new Employee("John", "Stanmore",Gender.male, 80000, "UK");
Employee employee8 = new Employee("Ben", "Hoskins", Gender.male,70000, "USA");
Employee employee9 = new Employee("Geir", "Ruine", Gender.male, 70000, "USA");
```

Here is my hibernate code:

```
final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

        try {

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();

            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
            projectionList.add(Projections.property("salary"));
            projectionList.add(Projections.property("firstName"));
            projectionList.add(Projections.property("lastName"));
            projectionList.add(Projections.property("Country"));
            projectionList.add(Projections.property("gender"));

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
            criteria.setFirstResult(3);
            criteria.setMaxResults(1);
            criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projectionList));
            criteria.addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.desc("salary"));
        //  criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class));
            Employee emp = (Employee) criteria.list().get(0);
            System.out.println(emp.getCountry());

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.flush();
            session.clear();

            session.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
```

This is giving me employee object with null values.

But
When i do `Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP or Transformers.To_List`, I Get the result in the form hashmap and List of String.

Suggest me how to transform to bean i.e. Employee object.

Comment: Why do you use a projection if you want to get Employee instances? Just don't use any projection, and any result transformer, and the query will return a List<Employee>. And frankly, given that your query is static, a standard JPQL query would be much more readable and concise: `select e from Employee e order by e.salary desc`.

Comment: I know this is possible from from HQL/SQL but I don't want use HQL or SQL queries. i want to use criteria object.

Comment: As I said: remove your projections and your result transformer.

Comment: Can you please write code and show me, what do mean exactly. if there are no duplicate records removing projection and result transforms works fine. how do you handle duplicate records?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("salary"));
        criteria.setFirstResult(3);// 0 based index; set 0 for 1st hishest salary,1 for second highest salary
        criteria.setMaxResults(1);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("salary")));
        int hishest = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();
```